# absolute css positions - firefox plugin to make it faster?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, firefox-addon

I do all my css work with firebug, using the up and down arrow keys to adjust `top` and `left` values.

Anyone come across a firefox addon that lets me drag stuff around and then copy and paste the top and left values?

---

edit: I have changed the question slightly from 'easier' to **faster**. Sorry for any confusion, I am not a beginner looking for tools to help me write css, simply to speed up my positioning slightly!

Comment: I'd suspect if you are doing so much absolute positioning, and moving elements that far, then you are probably doing too much absolute positioning. I'd aim to make more use of normal flow.

Comment: yes my whole site is absolutely positioned, i like being able to line things up all nice. only joking - absolute positioning is useful for some nested items

Answer (score 1):

I use the [MeasureIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/539/) addon for Firefox, which gives you a ruler. Drag from where you want the element to the top left of the screen and it'll give you the absolute position. You might need to adjust for scrolling but it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

I do the measurement part in Fireworks, Photoshop or any drawing program (Photofiltre, Paint.NET, etc or The Gimp), based on a template I was given. Not in the browser. And I certainly don't use absolute positioning for layout!

That said, here are some tools I found useful:

- MeasureIt
- [Pixel Perfect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7943) overlays a PNG over the page
- many plugins for Firebug exist, they can be found here: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions . **XRefresh** and a dual screen for example. **Firediff** could match your needs

Comment: yep, i already use all these except Firediff which is new to me, doesnt do what i'm looking for, but looks like a useful add on - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hjpdnlklajjpbihamlcpllppegpekicg

I made this because I agree with this question. It allows you to inspect and drag an element. Your new coordinates, calculated by Firebug will be updated when dragging ends.

Comment: strange link and not available

Answer (score -1):

Use dreamviewer, when you set css to absolute, in the preview mode you can drag and drop your element where ever you please two and CSS is generated automatically with the positions top, left where you placed your element

Comment: yes i remember this feature in Dreamweaver, though i really didn't like dreamweaver writing my css

Comment: well I don't use it at all since years now because it does generate bad code, but this is one of the ways you can accomplish this I couldn't think of others at this time.. but it should be fine for just css